# Bot won't register user reactions

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I have been trying to add a new command to a discord bot of mine and so far it's all working aside from trying to register when a user has reacted to a message. From what I can tell, the `user` field in the `filter` variable is null and undefined which makes it fail all the checks is my guess, but I don't know how I can change or fix that. The time out message I have works every time and messages in the channel

```
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('chess')
    .setDescription('Starts a game of chess with a specified user')
    
    .addUserOption(option => option.setName("user")
        .setDescription("User to play")
        .setRequired(true)),

    async execute(interaction) 
    {
        interaction.deferReply();
        interaction.deleteReply();
        
        let username = `${interaction.options.getUser('user')}`
        const message = await interaction.channel.send(`${interaction.user} challenges ` + username)
        message.react('✅').then(() => message.react('❌'))

        const filter = (reaction, user) => {          
            return ['✅', '❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === interaction.options.getUser('user')
        };
        message.awaitReactions({ filter, max: 1, time: 40000, errors: ['time'] })
            .then(collected => {
                const reaction = collected.first()
                
                if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅') 
                    interaction.channel.send(username + ' accepted.')
                    
                else 
                    interaction.channel.send(username + ' declined.')
                
            })
            .catch(() => {
                interaction.channel.send(username + ' has not responded and has timed out.')
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "null and undefined"? How can `user` be null and undefined at the same time?

Comment: I don't think `user.id` can ever be equal to `interaction.options.getUser('user')` since the former gives you a string while the latter gives you a `User` object. Maybe you can use this => `&& user.id === interaction.options.getUser('user').id`?

Comment: @Caladan the interaction.options.getUser('user') returns the id when not put in a string from what Ive seen and when I add .id, it still doesnt work and then I get a message saying the bot is thinking